# Django: How to display author of query of posts?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make individual pages for each author showing their name and posts. I can't seem to get the username displayed.

views.py

```
class UserProfileView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'howl/user-profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_howls'

    def get_queryset(self):
        author = self.request.user
        u = User.objects.get(username=author)
        return Howl.objects.filter(author=u)
```

models.py

```
class Howl(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Here is where I'm stuck.

user-profile.html

```
{% extends 'howl/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>User: {{user_howl.author}}</h1>

{% for user_howl in user_howls %}
<ul>
    <li>{{user_howl.content}}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

The content is displayed just fine, but the heading just says "User: ", how do I give it a context without using a for loop?
I've tried:

```
{% for author in user_howls.author %}
<h1>User: {{author}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% if user_howls.author %}
<h1>User: {{user_howl.author}}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Still the same outcome, displaying "User: "

Comment: `user_howl` vs `user_howls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your queryset is based on the posts belonging to the current user, you can shortcut all of this and just show the user directly:

```
User: {{ user }}
```

Answer (score 3):

`user_howls` is a queryset so it won't have an `author` attribute, you need to get the author of the iterated object

```
{% for howl in user_howls %}
<h1>User: {{ howl.author}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

More to the point though, it doesn't make sense to start from a `Howl` list, when you are just returning the results for the user_profile, nor does it make sense to use a `ListView`. so instead, start from the user and then look up its howls

```
user_obj.howl_set.all()
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I state the author only once?

Comment: What kind of view would I use if not ListView?

Comment: @user298519 - Well if you're looking to show the details of a user, then the `DetailView` might be a good place to start your research, a `ListView` is for showing a list of objects.